# PyQt Application load complete event

Tags: events, pyqt, loading

If my structure looks like this...

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog,QImage,QPixmap
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from appView import Ui_View 
# this is designer .ui file converted to .py via pyuic4 cmd

class AppWindow(QDialog, Ui_View):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setupEvents()
    def setupEvents():
        print ("setting up events")

def onResize(event):
        print event
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = AppWindow()
    myapp.resizeEvent = onResize
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I get application loading complete event from PyQt in
   `AppWindow` class, so that I know its contructor has finished running?
2. How can I get application resizing event in `AppWindow` class? 
   I can get
   this in the main function and tweak it, but if the `AppWindow` class is capable
   of listening and handling it: What is best way of doing it? Should
   this be ideally done as above?

Comment: What do you need these events _for_? What are you actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to prevent resizing of the window?

Comment: actually i am learning simplecv, attempting to create application for image processing. Detecting some stuff etc. i.e
application detect 10 images in a folder. when loaded. i wanted to read first image and display it
plus, if windows resizes, qscene and qview needs adjustments, for zoomed view etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWERS:

1. Just start a one-shot timer with your `QApplication` that calls the right method on `AppWindows`.
2. Just put the code of `onResize` in `AppWindows.resizeEvent`.

Example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog,QImage,QPixmap
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class AppWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        #self.setupUi(self)
        self.setupEvents()

    def setupEvents(self):
        print ("setting up events")

    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        print event

    def onQApplicationStarted(self):
        print 'started'

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = AppWindow()
    myapp.show()
    t = QtCore.QTimer()
    t.singleShot(0,myapp.onQApplicationStarted)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```